# Which service to create a screenshot of a html page on web app and save it?

Tags: cakephp, screenshot, html-to-jpeg

I am creating a web app(run on linux, PHP). In this application, after users log in, they will able to generate a postcard with their name on it.

Since the page of postcard is html(generated by cakephp), I want to take a screenshot of the central part of that page and save as an image.

Please recommend me any tool/plugin in order to do so. Free service/plugin is prefered.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

I have used the pdf part and it works great, there is a wkhtmltoimage download there that should help you with what you asking.

Comment: This is good for a full page/screen, but not for part of the page ("take a screenshot of the central part of that page")

Comment: It will make an image of what ever html you feed it, If you dont want the whole page do give it the whole page.